# Retrieve specific drive data - Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk

Tags: powershell, filter, wmi, wql, cim

I am attempting to retrieve the FreeSpace for a specific drive using Get-WmiObject.

Using Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk on my machine returns the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\Tools\Powershell> Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk | Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace
DeviceID  FreeSpace
--------  ---------
C:  47114498048
S:  9963356160
Z:  985061974016
```

I want to specifically request the FreeSpace dependent on the drive letter (DeviceID) I specify however I'm unsure how to do so as I'm rather new to powershell. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-Filter` parameter to filter the objects at the source:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk -Filter 'DeviceId = "C:"' | Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace

DeviceID   FreeSpace
--------   ---------
C:       14188314624
```

Filter expression `'DeviceId = "C:"'` is essentially the `WHERE` clause of a [WQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WQL) statement.

---

Note, however, that the `*-Cim-*` cmdlets have superseded the `*-Wmi*` cmdlets in PSv3+.

Fortunately, WQL is an implementation of [CQL (the CIM Query Language)](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0202_1.0.0.pdf), so the same filter can be used:

```
PS> Get-CimInstance Win32_logicaldisk -Filter 'DeviceId = "C:"' | Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace

DeviceID   FreeSpace
--------   ---------
C:       14188314624
```